# Cannot segue from MapKitView to Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, mapkit

I want to create a segue between a map view and a controller. However, holding Ctrl ket and trying to make a connection between the map view and controller doesn't work. I have seen people say that you can call it programmatically by using `performSegueWithIdentifier` but I can't even create a segue to assign an identifier to it so I can call it later on. If nothing works out I am just going to create a hidden button, make a segue and call that segue on map view click. But if there is a non-hack way of doing it, I would like to know.

Comment: To create a segue that you can invoke programatically you ctrl-drag from the view controller icon to the destination scene.  You can't initiate a segue from an MKMapView as it doesn't support actions

Comment: I am going to go off topic here. In order to simulate a click action, should I just create a gesture recognizer for it?

Comment: Normally you would trigger a segue when someone taps on an annotation - I would think there would be a risk of false triggering if you use a tap gesture recogniser, but you could try it

Comment: It worked. I disabled all the other gestures and added tap :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First understand what kind of segue you need. Probably you want to come back to the map with a back button. Easy way to accomplish this is by embedding the all the VC in navigation controller. We will do that at last.

Lets ctrl+drag from the first VC to the second one. Make sure you are zoomed out and you are selecting not the button but the whole VC. This way we create manual segue. Give a suitable name for the identifier because we need to refer to it in the code later on.

[image]

Now got to the inspector set the identifier as stated above. Make sure you select the round segue thing in-between the two VCs.
[image]

Then into the first VC, ctrl+drag from the map after zooming in to set a action. For my case, i have a button named pop and i will set a action by Ctrl+dragging it to implementation file.

After that i want the user to click the POP, in you case the map or marker, then fire the segue we created.

The code is:

```
- (IBAction)pop:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"push" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"push"]) {
        //get the presenting vc here
        id destionationVC=segue.destinationViewController;

        //put some values to it
        //destionationVC.value=2; //something;

        //done
    }
}
```

If you try to run now, you will crash. Because Push segues need to have UINavigationController as its root view controller. In doing so, we get a back button implemented for us automatically. So choose the First VC, in your case, MaPVC and choose embed in navigation controller. Like so,
[image]

Then run the app and you get to segue by clicking Pop in my case. Use the concept however you like if its applicable. Any questions welcomed?

P.S performSegueWithIdentifier in turns calls your implementation of -prepareSegue. If you don't implement this method, it calls the UIViewControllers -prepareSegue. Thats some inheritance going there. Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because I didn't know that one can create manual segues. However, you cannot add an action to MapView hence they can't have segues. So, I created a manual segue and then added a UITapGestureRecognizer to the MapView and added an action to the recognizer to perform the segue.